# Many numbers with pairwise differences squares

Tags: nt.number-theory

> How many different natural numbers are there such that the difference of any two is a perfect square?

I could find that with 'sums' instead of 'differences' this has been asked by Erdos and L. Moser (see [Guy: Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-26677-0), 3rd ed., p. 268), and that is open, with [six being the current record](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042115500281).

Comment: Just one unless you consider only the *positive* differences.

Answer (score 10):

Four is possible, an example is $0,451584,462400,485809$.
This solution comes from the example of a cuboid with integer sides, space diagonal and two out of three face diagonals given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCuboid.html).
I don't know for $5$ or more but it is probably a very hard question.