# Graph of number pairs summing to a square number

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics

Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}_+$ of positive integers and set $E = \big\{\{a,b\}: a\neq b\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \text{ and there is } n\in\mathbb{Z}_+: a+b = n^2\big\}$.

Does the graph $G=(\mathbb{Z}_+,E)$ have cliques of arbitrary sizes? If not, what is its chromatic number?

Comment: The clique number is an open problem of Erdos and Moser.  Choudhry constructed infinitely many sextuples here https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042115500281

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576986

Comment: Also Bombieri Lang would suggest that the clique number is finite.

Comment: I suppose, this should be known for the (positive) differences?

Comment: This last question also showed up on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374394/many-numbers-with-pairwise-differences-squares/374398

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022415/is-it-possible-to-split-the-natural-numbers-into-a-finite-number-of-sets-so-that

Comment: @VladMatei Thanks for your hint, didn't know that! So there are cliques of size 6; is it known whether the chromatic number is strictly larger than 6 - even infinite possibly?

Comment: Clique number is only a lower bound. On the other there are triangle free graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number. So my guess that asking about the chromatic number is way harder than asking about the clique number of this graph.

Comment: @VladMatei I knew about the triangle-free graphs. I suspect the chromatic number is $\aleph_0$ -- but my only reason is that infinite graphs tend to have either a trivially provable finite chromatic number - or infinite chromatic number. (Exception: the graph defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where points are joined by an edge iff their Euclidean distance is $1$. The chromatic number is known to lie in the interval $[4,7]$.)